# ¿Cómo crear un Array con nombre dinámico y parámetros dinámicos en JavaScript dentro de una función?

Tags: javascript, array, function

Quiero que no solo el contenido del array sea dinámico si no que el nombre del array también sea dinámico que pueda llamar a la función con un nombre y unos parámetros y se cree el array.

```js
                //Lo que quiero es crear una funcion con parametros para crear un Array
                function crearArrays(nombreArray,fruta,color){
                    nombreArray = [fruta,color];//el nombre del array es uno de los parametros
                }

                crearArrays('frutas','manzana','verde'); // aqui le doy los parametros 
                
                console.log(frutas);
                document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = frutas;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Javascript, las variables **no locales** y **no constantes** no son mas que atributos del objeto global `window`.

Por lo tanto, lo que pides es muy sencillo:

```js
function crearArray( nombreArray, ...args ) {
    window[nombreArray] = [ ...args ];
}

crearArray( 'prueba', 1, 2, 'hola', 'y', 'adios' );

console.log( prueba );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)